# Proper Parsing Strategy using PLY.yacc

Tags: php, python, parsing, lexical-analysis, ply

I am writing a PHP parser in PLY in order to teach myself the concepts of lexing/parsing.

I have the lexer tokens created for a very simple PHP code snippet but I am stuck on the proper way to parse.

Here is the code snippet I am trying to lex/parse:

```
  <?php if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $msg = "Hello, " . $name . "!";
        $encoded = htmlspecialchars($msg);
  }
  ?>
```

My goal is to trace the user-input to determine that is has indeed reached the `htmlspecialchars()` method. My current parsing strategy gets me as far as the parsing to line 2

`$name = $_REQUEST['name'];`

but I have no idea what the proper way to parse line 3:

`$msg = "Hello, " . $name . "!";`

The complication is that I will never be certain how many concatenations will take place on my user-input and I feel it is wrong to "hard code" just to successfully parse the example code. For example with this line I'm interested in the fact that the `$msg` variable includes my user-supplied data (from `$name` variable)

I have tried parsing this token in probably the worst possible way just to test if I could reach it but when I run my script it says `WARNING: Symbol 'wrong' is unreachable`

```
def p_wrong(p):
    '''wrong : VARIABLE EQUALS QUOTED_ENCAPSED_STRING DOT VARIABLE DOT QUOTED_ENCAPSED_STRING SEMICOLON'''
    print "wrong"
```

So I am hoping for guidance I how to understand how to parse line #3 in such a way that it won't matter how many concatenations or other operations take place on the variables I am tracing. I have a feeling this is where a lesson on BNF grammar or the wonderfully painful complexities of parsing will begin. But I want to learn I just don't know where to start.

Here is my complete code at this point:

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

string = """<?php if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
               $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
               $msg = "Hello, " . $name . "!";
               $encoded = htmlspecialchars($msg);
}
?>"""

delimeters = ('LPAREN', 'RPAREN', 'LBRACKET', 'RBRACKET')

tokens = delimeters + (
    "CHAR",
    "NUM",
    "OPEN_TAG",
    "CLOSE_TAG",
    "VARIABLE",
    "CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
    "ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE",
    "QUOTED_ENCAPSED_STRING",
    "LCURLYBRACKET",
    "RCURLYBRACKET",
    "EQUALS",
    "SEMICOLON",
    "QUOTE",
    "DOT",
    "IF"
)

t_ignore         = " \t"
t_CHAR           = r"[a-z]"
t_LPAREN         = r'\('
t_RPAREN         = r'\)'
t_RBRACKET       = r'\]'
t_LBRACKET       = r'\['
t_RCURLYBRACKET  = r'\}'
t_LCURLYBRACKET  = r'\{'
t_EQUALS         = r'='
t_SEMICOLON      = r';'
t_DOT            = r'\.'


def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count("\n")

def t_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING(t):
    r"'([^\\']|\\(.|\n))*'"
    t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count("\n")
    return t

def t_QUOTED_ENCAPSED_STRING(t):
    r"""\"([^\\"]|\\(.|\n))*\""""
    t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count("\n")
    return t

def t_OPEN_TAG(t):
    r'<[?%]((php[ \t\r\n]?)|=)?'
    if '=' in t.value: t.type = 'OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO'
    t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count("\n")
    return t

def t_CLOSE_TAG(t):
    r'[?%]>\r?\n?'
    t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count("\n")
    #t.lexer.begin('INITIAL')
    return t

def t_VARIABLE(t):
    r'\$[A-Za-z_][\w_]*'
    return t

def t_NUM(t):
    r"\d+"
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t

def t_error(t):
    print t.lexer.current_state
    print dir(t.lexer)
    raise TypeError("unknown char '%s'"%(t.value))

lexer = lex.lex()

lex.input(string)
for tok in iter(lex.token, None):
    print repr(tok.type), repr(tok.value)


##now for the parsing

"""
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$msg = "Hello, " . $name . "!";    
"""

def p_assign(p):
    '''assign : VARIABLE EQUALS input'''
    print "assign rule"
    print p[1],p[2],p[3]
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_input(p):
    '''input : VARIABLE LBRACKET CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING RBRACKET SEMICOLON
             | VARIABLE LBRACKET QUOTED_ENCAPSED_STRING RBRACKET SEMICOLON'''
    print "input rule"
    value =  p[1]+p[2]+p[3]+p[4]+p[5]
    p[0] = value

def p_wrong(p):
    '''wrong : VARIABLE EQUALS QUOTED_ENCAPSED_STRING DOT VARIABLE DOT QUOTED_ENCAPSED_STRING SEMICOLON'''
    print "wrong"    


yacc.yacc()
yacc.parse(string)
```

And the results:

```
...
WARNING: There is 1 unused rule
WARNING: Symbol 'wrong' is unreachable
Generating LALR tables
yacc: Syntax error at line 6, token=OPEN_TAG
input rule
assign rule
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
yacc: Syntax error at line 8, token=VARIABLE
```

My (incorrect) attempt at parsing line 3 (with the format hard-coded in the parser rule p_wrong) doesn't even get hit. But I would just like some guidance on how to proceed to parse this simple code block.

**Desired output**

Ideally I will have results that allow me to trace the user input something like this:

```
user-input -> $name -> $msg -> htmlspecialchars($msg)
```

Comment: Have you looked at example expression grammars? The [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples), for example, works through several iterations of an expression calculator,  ending with a grammar which includes variable assignment and function calls.

Comment: @rici I went through those examples but I guess I lack the knowledge on how to apply any of that to my scenario. For example I don't see in there how to handle situations where you have a variable quantity of certain statements for example how to handle `VARIABLE EQUALS VARIABLE CONCAT VARIABLE` and `VARIABLE EQUALS VARIABLE CONCAT VARIABLE CONCAT VARIABLE` in the same parsing rule without knowing how many concatenations will be made.

Comment: Why do you think that's different from handling a+b+c ? You don't know how many additions there are, either. Both `+` and concat are just binary operators.

Answer (score 0):

To parse a variable with an arbitrary number of dots, we can use a recursive definition like the following:

```
expression : VARIABLE
           | VARIABLE DOT expression
```